# reference variables and inheritence

Tags: c++, reference, vptr

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void func() {printf("Parent\n");}
};

class Child1 : public Parent
{
    virtual void func() {printf("Child1\n");}
};

class Child2 : public Parent
{
    virtual void func() {printf("Child2\n");}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Parent & obj = Child1();
    obj.func();
    obj = Child2();
    obj.func();
    return 0;
}
```

yields the following results:

```
expected: Child1 Child2.

actual: Child1 Child1.
```

(compiled on VS2010)

I guess that the vptr is not changed by the assignment. It there a way to cause it to be re-created (other than using a pointer to Parent and assigning to it using new)?

thanks

Comment: References cannot be reseated! Moreover temporaries cannot be bound to non constant references. Your code is ill-formed

Comment: Why _would_ you do this with a reference in the first place? If you change `obj`, make it either an object or a pointer.

Comment: This will not even compile! Post some real code here, please.

Comment: it does compile: 
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: MSVC++ supports many non standard extensions. You shouldn't be surprised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the default assignment operator on obj, which is still of type Child1, with an argument of type Child2. The object itself is still of type `Child1`. You can verify this by implementing `operator =` on all 3 classes, and inserting a print statement there.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of using polymorphism on a ref var?

Comment: @OrenS. You are using polymorphism. That's why the call to Child1::func works. But you don't have an object of type Child2, but Child1.

Comment: The only way you can do **rebindable** polymorphics is with pointers. For hopefully obvious reasons, I recommend using smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

References cannot be reseated - they refer to the same object for their entire lifetime. If you want something that can change the object it refers to then you need to use a [smart] pointer instead of a reference.

What you're doing here is [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) an instance of `Child2` by assigning it to an instance of `Child1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Parent & obj = Child1();
```

You create a reference to an object of type `Child1`. This is like saying

```
Child1 c1;
Parent& obj = c1;
```

`obj` is now just a different name for `c1`, which is an object of type `Child1`.

```
obj = Child2();
obj.func();
```

Now, this is like saying

```
c1 = Child2();
c1.func();
```

so you see, you're still calling `func` on an object of type `Child1`.

Answer (score 1):

Two fundamental properties in C++: an object, once created, never
changes its type, and a reference, once initialized, always refers to
the same object.

What's happening here is that you are calling the compiler supplied
non-virtual `operator=` for `Parent`, which is almost certainly not what
you wanted.  More generally, however, assignment and inheritance don't
work well together (precisely because you can't change the type of an
object); most of the time, when using inheritance, you should ban
assignment (by inheriting from `boost::noncopyable`, for example).  It's
possible to implement value semantics for a polymorphic class, using the
letter/envelope idiom, but it's a heavy solution, and rarely
appropriate.

(I might add that your code doesn't compile with a C++ compiler.  You're
initializing a reference to a non-const with a temporary, which isn't
legal C++.  Allowing this is a Microsoft extension.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should give an error in compilation. You can not assign a temporary variable (created by `Child2()`) to a reference variable. You have to create an instance before of `Child2`, and assign that variable to the reverence.

Comment: @OrenS. I missread the error, it's actually for the `Parent & obj = Child1();` line I get an error.

Comment: `g++` doesn't compile this, but of course you can always create a variable of type `Child1` and assign from there. Fascinating that VS2010 compiles this in the first place.